Cant put tsparticle.js component on each carousel slide of React.js
I am using the tsparticle.js with React and Tailwind css for design in my code in the carousel slides but i cant see that on each slide. It appears only on first slide. The rest of the slides are blank. Where i used map function to  assign the data to each slide.

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './TypedText';
import ParticlesComponent from './ParticlesComponents'; // Corrected import path

import image1 from '../assets/images/sliderimg1.jpg';
import image2 from '../assets/images/sliderimg2.jpg';
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../index.css';

const carouselMatter = [
  {
    image: image1,
    h2: ["Title for Item1"],
    matter: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nam illum repellat aliquam. Inventore facere quod aspernatur, incidunt dolore architecto asperiores a, nobis repudiandae, nulla minima magni quis. Esse, beatae.",
  },
  {
    image: image2,
    h2: ["Title for Item2"],
    matter: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nam illum repellat aliquam. Inventore facere quod aspernatur, incidunt dolore architecto asperiores a, nobis repudiandae, nulla minima magni quis. Esse, beatae.",
  },
];

const MainCarousel = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);
  const touchStartX = useRef(0);
  const touchEndX = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const autoplay = setInterval(() => {
      goToNextSlide();
    }, 4000);

    return () => clearInterval(autoplay);
  }, [currentIndex]);

  const goToNextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % carouselMatter.length);
  };

  const goToPrevSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + carouselMatter.length) % carouselMatter.length);
  };

  const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
    touchStartX.current = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
  };

  const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
    touchEndX.current = e.targetTouches[0].clientX;
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = () => {
    if (touchStartX.current - touchEndX.current > 50) {
      goToNextSlide();
    }

    if (touchStartX.current - touchEndX.current < -50) {
      goToPrevSlide();
    }
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    touchStartX.current = e.clientX;
  };

  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    touchEndX.current = e.clientX;
    if (touchStartX.current - touchEndX.current > 50) {
      goToNextSlide();
    }

    if (touchStartX.current - touchEndX.current < -50) {
      goToPrevSlide();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative w-full max-h-5xl mx-auto overflow-hidden">
      <div
        ref={carouselRef}
        className="overflow-hidden"
        onTouchStart={handleTouchStart}
        onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
        onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      >
        <div
          className="relative flex transition-transform duration-500"
          style={{ transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)` }}
        >
          {carouselMatter.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="relative min-w-full">
              <img
                src={item.image}
                alt={`Slide ${index}`}
                className="w-full h-128 object-cover"
                onDragStart={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
              />
              <div className="absolute inset-0">
                <ParticlesComponent id={`particleJs-${index}`} />
              </div>
              <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 flex items-center justify-start md:px-24 text-white">
                <div className="carousel-item-matter max-w-128 z-10">
                  <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold sliding-text">
                    <MyComponent h2title={item.h2} />
                  </h2>
                  <p>{item.matter}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={goToPrevSlide}
        className="absolute h-full top-1/2 left-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 bg-gray-300 opacity-30 text-black font-bold p-2 rounded-sm"
      >
        ‹
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={goToNextSlide}
        className="absolute h-full top-1/2 right-0 transform -translate-y-1/2 bg-gray-300 opacity-30 text-black font-bold p-2 rounded-sm"
      >
        ›
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainCarousel;

I want that tsparticles.js to be appear on each slide of the carousel which i made it in reactjs.

Make sure your tsParticles configuration has fullscreen disabled. Additionally, set the position of the particle canvas to relative, and apply absolute positioning to the container that holds all the slides, since the container is not moving right or left, but the slides are.
This way, the tsParticles component will stay fixed to the container of all the sliders.
